# Observation Specific Confidence for Random Forests in R and Python

Tags: python, r, classification, binary-tree, random-forest

I have a classification task for which I have a binary outcome -- however, I need to know the level of confidence in classifying each row (the row could be a observation, participant, subject, etc.).

Confidence could be a residual for the row, specificity, sensitivity/Recall, or f-score for the decision node for associated with a rows terminal node.

I need to do my initial analysis in R and productionalize the analysis using Python.  So I'd prefer a package the common to both languages.

Does such a package exist?

Comment: Interesting question, however, it's off topic here as recommendations are considered too much based on opinions; try stats.stackexchange.com instead. That said, expressing uncertainty in the context of decision problems requires that the uncertainty must work like probability, under pretty mild assumptions. The RF implementation in R expresses uncertainty about outcomes as a vote fraction, which is not a probability (easy to make up examples where all trees in a forest agree, but the posterior class probability is less than 1). My advice is to work with a model which outputs probabilities.

Comment: E.g. logistic regression outputs a probability, neural networks with sigmoid or softmax output probability. Widely-used models which don't include RF as mentioned, and SVM.

Comment: @RobertDodier however, I specified that confidence could be one of several objective measures.  Cute philosophical argument though…

Answer (score 0):

Post details a method to whereby a binary decision tree can produce 0 to 1 continuous likelihood of belonging to one of two groups.

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/358948/how-to-make-the-randomforest-trees-vote-decimals-but-not-binary